# deja-dup: How to restore a LUbuntu 18.04.5 backup to Ubuntu 20.04.2, including with app settings and app local folders?

Tags: lubuntu, thunderbird, home-directory, restore, deja-dup

BACKGROUND
I have an old PC running LUbuntu 18.04.5, and a newer PC on which I plan to run LUbuntu 20.04.2 or Ubuntu 20.04.2 (which I will first download to a DVD).

Indications from the GUI of Deja-Dup are that a backup of the Home folder in LUbuntu 18.04.5 (on the older PC) completed (to an external HDD) .

QUESTIONS/REQUESTS
On the newer PC, would there be fewer problems/issues while restoring from my backup (using deja-dup) if I were to start out with LUbuntu 18.04.5 on the newer PC initially? Or would it be fine to startout from either LUbuntu 20.04.2 or Ubuntu 20.04.2 on the newer PC?

When I 'restore' the LUbuntu 18.04.5 Home folder to Ubuntu 20.04.2 using Deja-Dup, as I plan to do, do I then have to do anything special to make sure that the settings and local folders for apps are successfully brought over?
My main concern is to be sure that I successfully move over my local (email) folders and my email account in Thunderbird, and my bookmarks, history, extensions, open sessions, etc. in Firefox.
It would be nice, too, to find Zoom running as it was running before the move to Ubuntu 20.04.2.

Additionally, I don't want any of the hidden files in the freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 to be 'damaged' by the restore process using deja-dup, of course.

ALSO: When restoring using deja-dup, does it matter that the names associated with the Home folders in LUbuntu 18.04.5 and in Ubuntu 20.04.2 are slightly different (for example Pete and pete)?

If you provide a solutions, please include explicit step-by-step instructions, preferably, if possible, involving GUIs, rather than Terminal.
If you do cite Terminal commands, it's essential for me that you include explicit step-by-step examples. As only one example, I wouldn't yet know how to move between directories in Terminal.

Comment: This is such a specific situation it will be hard to give you a definite solution unless someone went through the exact process. Any other answer would be opinion based. Having said that, my advice is 1. keep the username (and home folder name) same in the new computer to avoid any confusion. 2. After you install Ubuntu 20.04, **do not** open Thunderbird, Firefox, etc. until you restore the profiles from the backup. If you do, a set of default profiles will be created and the profiles restored from the backup may or may not replace them.

Comment: If the first thing you do is restore from backup, there won't be much in the hidden files to be damaged. In any case, everything I said is hypothetical, as I have never used Lubuntu and tried to restore made from Lubuntu into Ubuntu. If you don't get any answers here, I would say you do it anyway, and then write your own answer in case someone else finds your experience helpful.

Comment: @user68186 . I have read the answer to the posting at discourse.lubuntu.me/t/18-04-5-lts-to-20-04-1-lts-update/1649/2. And I have read the article at https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today . The two articles seem mutually contradictory. I notice that the lubuntu.me article post dates the other article by about 5 months. And now is 10 months later. Would you agree I need clearer and updated directions on how to move over my local (email) folders and my email account in Thunderbird, and my bookmarks, history, extensions, open sessions, etc. in Firefox?

Comment: Neither the discourse discussion nor the blog post applies to your question. Your question is about restoring from backup to a new computer. The two links are about upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. The discourse link is about Lubuntu. Lubuntu used LXDE in 18.04, and LXQT in 20.04. Because of this change in technology upgrade is not recommended. Ubuntu (note, no L) does not use either LXDE or LXQT. So the blog does not talk about the LXDE -> LXQT transition problems.